# Remove Github Repos from Careers Profile

Tags: support, jobs, github

I connected my careers account to my github repos. However I only have forked projects there where I am not a project member, so I have no description or ownership for them.

Now I want to remove those repos as they have nothing to do with me, but do not see how to do so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on edit next to your project in Open Source section in Home, 
[image]

and then on remove on the right side

[image]

Comment: Sweet works like a charm. +1 for the graphic and pointers.