# If there's an "add all my repositories", there should be a "remove all my repositories"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, github

On my Stack Overflow Careers profile page, I was trying to add a new GitHub repository, which wasn't showing up on the list, so I clicked "update/add all my repositories". That was a mistake - the repositories I didn't want on my profile all got added, the new one didn't show up, and worse, <del>I have no idea how</del> it'll be frustrating to take them off. I'm sure there's some option somewhere for removing repositories from my profile, but I'd like a to remove them all at once.

[image]

EDIT: On a side note, removing them manually is a [little inconvenient too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124889/remove-github-repos-from-careers-profile); could we have this option on the import page, please?

Comment: ...And they say the SO moderators don't like fun!